# What do you call for approximations having a characteristic "Z" / really-sharp curve to it?

Tags: functions

It's called a [Sigmoid/logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for an "S" shaped curve of a mathematical function. What's the name for a "Z" or a sharp counter-part to it or is there no name for such?

Answer (score 1):

A step function. That's actually a bit broader. The Heaviside step function 
$$H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{if } x < 0 \\
1 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, found it. It's called a [Hard-Sigmoid][1]

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_sigmoid. Examples include; [Piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function)